# Open file in different drive from the one where the server script runs

Tags: javascript, html, perl, window.open, drive

I am developing a Perl program, and I have to produce a `.csv` file containing the data obtained from an executed query. My program works well, and it produces the .csv file correctly and into the path I want, which is `D:\\Tabelle\name_of_the_csv_file.csv` .
My inetpub folder is inside the `C:\\` drive, so the program.

The problem is, I generate an HTML page containing a button with the `"onclick"` property set to window.open(`D:\\Tabelle\name_of_the_csv_file.csv`), in order to allow the user to download the file if he wants, but when I click on it, it just opens a blank page, without anything inside it.
Here's the HTML part of my page where I have the button:

```
     <form action='' method=get>
         <table align="center">
           <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan=3>
                       <input align="middle" type=button name="csvObtain" value="Esporta tabella in .csv" onclick="window.open('d:\tabelle\Tabella-2012-8-8-12.11.30.csv')">
                </td>

           </tr>
         </table>
    </form>
```

Could someone help me resolving this? Do I have to create a different JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using window.open like this ,

```
   window.open(D:\Tabelle\name_of_the_csv_file.csv)
```

it shall refer to the path on client machine, since the path is in javascript. if you want the file to be available as downloadable item, just map the `D\tabelle` folder as child directory(virtual dir) in your application and use relative path for the file.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Since I am pretty noob with IIS (I have just started using it) could you please explain me how to map the folder?

Comment: Furqan, thanks to your answer I managed to create the virtual directory, and now everything works fine. Thank you so much, you were very helpful to me.